# Sorting common array of attributes

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, algorithm, underscore.js

I'm struggling with an array problem that I'm sure has been solved before.  The best analogy I can think of is a product comparison feature where 2-3 products are selected and their characteristics are listed for the user to compare.

I have 2-3 arrays of characteristics.  The arrays can have the same characteristics. I need to display a table of the arrays side-by-side where the elements are sorted by "most common." So, if all three arrays have the same characteristic it would be at the top.  Then two similar characteristics would be listed, etc.  If two arrays shared a characteristic, the third array would have a blank cell.

The backend is written in PHP. The frontend is Javascript.  I am using Underscore for some other functionality, so it's array functions are available.

I just can't get my head around the combinations of things I would have to do to make this work!  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a structure of your arrays so that we get an idea of your array structure. Would help a lot.

Comment: How do you get the data? Likely a database sorting is more appropriate.

Comment: what do you mean by `characteristics` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution which I think covers this problem, working with the advice from mainegreen in using a secondary structure to record the frequency of each category, and a custom sort function which compares using the values of this frequency array. Example implementation below;

```
function getCategories(products) {
var categories = [], frequency = {};
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    for (var c in products[i]) {
        if (products[i].hasOwnProperty(c)) {
            if (frequency.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
                frequency[c]++;
            } else {
                categories.push(c);
                frequency[c] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
categories.sort(function (a,b) { return frequency[b]-frequency[a]; });
return categories;
}
```

This would work with an array of products as below;

```
var products = [
    {
        cat1: 'val1',
        cat2: 'val1',
    }, {
        cat2: 'val2',
        cat3: 'val2',
    }, {
        cat2: 'val3',
        cat3: 'val3',
        cat4: 'val3',
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, which I'm not sure I do, but if you are trying to sort items in multiple arrays in such a way that the 'characteristics' of each array are sorted that the most shared is listed at the top, then could you not have a secondary array that you use to implement a shared characteristic count? So you would loop through your first set of arrays and as each characteristic is found, you increment a counter for that characteristic.

Then, when you are on the display routine you would have a loop routine work on the array that you used to tally the characteristic counts?

Answer (score 0):

You could merge `array_keys()` from the products to compare and then loop through the keys (== "characteristics") and categorize them into, say, three new arrays ('shared', 'common', 'uncommon').

Having that array, rebuild the product arrays leaving empty fields for non-used keys.